# Include Version Labels when exporting via DFC (Documentum)

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, dfc

I am exporting a document that has the following version labels: "V1, CURRENT, 1.2"

But my exported XML document only includes this text: dctm:version_label="CURRENT".

Anyone know how I can export all of the version labels into the XML? I am using the following code:

```
IDfExportOperation exportOperation = clientx.getExportOperation();
exportOperation.setDestinationDirectory(exportDirectory);
IDfExportNode node = (IDfExportNode) exportOperation.add(myVirtDoc.asVirtualDocument("CURRENT",false));



exportOperation.setIncludeDCTMAttrsInXML(true);


node.setFormat("");
exportOperation.execute();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OOTB feature for this. I had to grab the attributes then open up the exported XML and stick them in.